# Get five largest values from a column of a Dataframe inside a List

Tags: r

I have a list with 12 dataframes, each of them has 9 columns. The number of rows vaires.
Now I want to itterate over the list and get the five largest values of the column `Sum_of_weights` for each dataframe.

I was only able to solve my problem if I import the list into my enviroment and work with that, but there must be a more elegant solution. I think it should be possible with `lapply`, but I can't get my head around.

Each df looks something along these lines:

```
 $ Utilities                 :'data.frame': 28 obs. of  10 variables:
 .. $ Price_to_Book      : num [1:28] 164 177 102 118 199 191 245 99 287 126 ...
 .. $ Price_Earnings     : num [1:28] 39 253 202 272 361 178 303 212 301 215 ...
 .. $ Dividend_Yield     : num [1:28] 475 427 441 433 254 494 394 443 444 409 ...
 .. $ Free_Cashflow_Yield: num [1:28] 63 67 98 145 80 188 95 71 62 83 ...
 .. $ Operation_Margin   : num [1:28] 229 286 257 355 425 204 311 329 435 247 ...
 .. $ Debt_to_Equity     : num [1:28] 480 312 320 327 356 430 425 311 426 314 ...
 .. $ Earnings_Growth    : num [1:28] 237 235 214 131 249 368 134 141 223 180 ...
 .. $ Return on_Capital  : num [1:28] 123 186 168 187 162 191 158 165 176 156 ...
 .. $ Sum_of_weights     : num [1:28] 1810 1943 1802 1968 2086 ...
 .. $ Sector             : Factor w/ 11 levels "Consumer Discretionary",..: 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
 .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:28] "AES.CORP" "ALLIANT.ENERGY.CORP" "AMEREN.CORPORATION" "AMERICAN.ELECTRIC.POWER" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

Values only

```
lapply(your_list, function(d) head(d$sum_of_weights[order(-d$sum_of_weights)], 5))
```

With row names:

```
lapply(your_list, function(d) head(d["sum_of_weights"][order(-d$sum_of_weights)], 5))
```

With whole row:

```
lapply(your_list, function(d) head(d[order(-d$sum_of_weights), ], 5))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works just fine. Would be even better if it would tell me the index aswell, but I'm sure I'll find a way. Thanks again

Comment: Just ask for what you want in the question and you can probably get it.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your effort!

Comment: computationally it's more efficient to write `d[head(order(...)),]`, so that only the relevant subset of the data.frame is ordered.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
library(dplyr);library(purrr)
your_list %>% map(top_n, 5, sum_of_weights)
```

will probably do it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works aswell and even prints the whole row! Never used purrr before, but seems like a handy package. Thank you!

Comment: note that `top_n` and `head(order(.))` handle ties differently, e.g., `tibble(x=rep(1, 10)) %>% top_n(6)` returns all 10 rows whereas `head(order())` returns the first 6